# Discord.py import updated module

Tags: discord.py

I have 2 py files for a Discord bot. One is for variables and the other one the common file for the input commands. Here they are:

*desc.py* for the variables:

```
    nmembers1 = str(nmembers) + "/50"
    dtag = data["tag"]
    dname = data["name"]
```

*bot.py*

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands, tasks
from itertools import cycle
import subprocess
from desc import *

@bot.command()
async def clan1(ctx):
    embed = discord.Embed(title=dname, color=0x00d166)
    embed.add_field(name="Membres", value=f" {nmembers1}", inline=False)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

It works this way, however when variables in desc.py change, it doesn't change the results on "clan1" command until I restart bot.py.
I'd like a way to reload desc.py on bot.py. I look for the reload/importlib option (Python version 3.7.2) but without any success. I even to put "from desc import *" in the bot command but it doesn't let me do, I have this error:

```
    @bot.command()
    ^
SyntaxError: import * only allowed at module level
```

Any idea ? thanks a lot !

Comment: You can't. The bot requires to restart in order to get the file loaded. You should have this data stored in some kind of JSON file and then use `json` module to read that JSON file.

Comment: how would you do it ?

Comment: I showed an easier way of doing that, Check my answer let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Shortest way of doing this is import the module when doing the task related to that module. As for you;

Instead of importing the module with other modules on top, Simply do it when sending embed. Firstly remove the import on top then;

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands, tasks
from itertools import cycle
import subprocess
# removed import from here.

@bot.command()
async def clan1(ctx):
    import desc # imported desc here.
    embed = discord.Embed(title=desc.dname, color=0x00d166)
    embed.add_field(name="Members", value=f" {desc.nmembers1}", inline=False)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

So, Essentially you are not creating a global import, You are importing it when you are sending your embed, What this will do is that even when you're bot is running, You can modify variables in that file and when you will run the `clan1` command the module will import completely fresh with all changes and updated value will appear, Instead of old value.

A better way of doing that is JSON files or a database, but you can also do this, It will work.